# How to fit forks to fixie frame

Tags: frames, fork, fixed-gear, stem

I have just ordered a fixie frame with no forks.

I will need to order a set of forks and cut them correctly (to the right size) so I can install my headset.

Are there any tips/ tutorials on how to do this correctly the first time and avoid having cut the forks tube too short?

thanks,

Comment: Yes, I use spacers

Answer (score 3):

Park tool has plenty of information on how to do this, including [how to cut a fork](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/fork-steering-column-length-and-sizing) (and what tools are useful, namely a saw, a vise and a saw guide). They also have other directions, e.g. [how to prep a frame for headset installation](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/head-tube-reaming-and-facing) and what not.

Depending on the tools you have, and how prepared the frame comes, you may want to leave some of the preparation to a bike shop (e.g. very few home mechanics are equipped to ream/face a frame properly).